# Replacing a matched string occurring after another specific string in a file

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a config file (`ssl.cfg`) for SSL requests:

```
oid_section = OIDs

[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

attributes = v3_req

[OIDs]
OrganizationID = 2.5.4.97        # Don't touch this

[dn]
C = FO
ST = Foobar Monarchy
O = Lorem Ipsum
CN = specific.domain.com
OrganizationID = ABCDE-12345     # Change this
#...

[v3_req]
#...
```

I'm trying to replace *the second* `OrganizationID`'s value (`ABCDE-12345`) with a new value, `ABCDE-98765`.

The problem is that most matches against `OrganizationID` conflict between the two identical names, which have to be the same (the one under `[OIDs]` section is marking a label; the second occurence is actually *using* the label).

Things that I've tried:

**1) Adapted code from this answer ([Replace line after match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20470583)) on Stack Overflow:**

```
REQ_ID="ABCDE-98765"
sed -i "/CN =/!b;n;c\\OrganizationID = ${REQ_ID}" ssl.cfg
```

- matches the previous line, `CN = ...`
- `!b` breaks the current match
- `n` scans the next line
- `c` changes the selected line with text that follows (`\` prints a new line; escaped (`\\`) because of double-quotes)

I don't really like this solution, because of its dependency on the position of the previous line. If someone manually swaps the CN to a different line, this will break.

**2) Using the previous attempt's knowledge**

```
REQ_ID="ABCDE-98765"
sed -i "/\\\[dn\\\]/!b;/OrganizationID/c\\OrganizationID = ${REQ_ID}" ssl.cfg
```

Here, I tried:

- matching `[dn]` (double-escaped `[` and `]`)
- breaking the current match
- Looking for the next occurence of OrganizationID from that point onward
- replacing using `c\...`

This doesn't work; I have a feeling the second match goes from the top all over again.
I've noticed that if both occurences are matched, neither seem to change.

I'm specifically looking for a way how to match the OrgID without caring about its position within [dn].
The string `ABCDE-` in its value will likely not change, but I'd prefer not to depend on it.
the OID `2.5.4.97` **won't change**.

**To summarize:**

1. Is there a way to look through a file from a specific line onwards? (using the `[dn]` tag)
2. Is there maybe some alternate way how to reach said goal? (`awk`? other sysutils + pipes? ...)

(my apologies for the confusing title; I don't know how to word it better)

Comment: Welcome to the site. It should be possible to solve your problem with `awk`. Are the key-value pairs always sepated by "key" "blank" "equal" "blank" "value" or can it be that there is no whitespace around the `=` sign?

Comment: Generally, yes - whitespaces will likely stay there regardless. Ideally, their presence wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

The following `awk` code will change the value of the line starting with `OrganizationID` to whatever you choose, but only in the section `[dn]`, and only on the first occurence of that key:

```
awk -F'=' -v OFS='=' '$0=="[dn]"{f=1} (f)&&$1~/^OrganizationID/{$2="Something-New"; f=0} 1' ssl.cfg
```

If you want to avoid hard-coding the replacement, you can import it as in

```
req_id="Something-New"
awk -F'=' -v OFS='=' -v repl="$req_id" '$0=="[dn]"{f=1} (f)&&$1~/^OrganizationID/{$2=repl; f=0} 1' ssl.cfg
```

*(but note that escape sequences in the variable will be interpreted by `awk`, so if you need literal backslashes, special precautions are necessary. See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for further reading)*.

The above code does the following:

- It considers the `=` as field separator for input (`-F'='`) and output (`-v OFS='='`), so internally, the line will be split at every `=` into "columns", and the output lines will be assembled by concatenating the field entries with `=` in between.
- If the entire current line (`$0`) only consists of the section header `[dn]`, a flag `f` will be set to 1 to indicate that the correct section was found.
- If we are in the correct section, and the first field (`$1`, i.e. the string before the first `=`) starts with `OrganizationID`, then the second field (`$2`, i.e. the string after the first `=`) is replaced by the content of the `awk` variable `repl`, which we have set to the content of the *shell* variable `$req_id` via the `-v repl="$req_id"` option. It also resets the flag so we don't replace the value for any other occurence of `OrganizationID`.
- The "lone" `1` outside of the rules blocks `{ ... }` is a shorthand notation and means "print the current line with all modifications made by the previous rules". The idea behind this mechanism is actually that you can state any condition *outside of the rules blocks* that, if it evaluates to `true` (or non-zero), makes `awk` print the current line (e.g. `awk 'FNR==1'` would print only the first line, because the internal line counter `FNR` is equal to `1` only on that line).

  Note that without any explicit `print`/`printf` command inside the rule blocks, or the "global" condition evaluating to `true`, `awk` will *not* print the current line.

Output for your example:

```
oid_section = OIDs

[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

attributes = v3_req

[OIDs]
OrganizationID = 2.5.4.97        # Don't touch this

[dn]
C = FO
ST = Foobar Monarchy
O = Lorem Ipsum
CN = specific.domain.com
OrganizationID =Something-New
#...

[v3_req]
```

This code will not modify the file but print the result to the console (so you can check if it is correct first). Once you are satisfied, either redirect the output to a new file and then replace manually, or - if your `awk` supports it - use the `-i inplace` extension (works on recent GNU `awk` implementations).

```
awk -F"=" -v OFS="=" '.. etc ..' ssl.cfg > ssl.cfg.new
```

or

```
awk -i inplace -F"=" -v OFS="=" '.. etc ..' ssl.cfg
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `1` at the end of the code string? `... f=0} 1' ssl.cfg`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v org='ABCDE-12345' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '
    $1 == "[dn]" {
        $0 = "\n" $0
        sub(/\nOrganizationID[[:space:]]*=[^\n]*/,"\nOrganizationID = " org)
        sub(/^\n/,"")
    }
    { print }
' file
oid_section = OIDs

[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

attributes = v3_req

[OIDs]
OrganizationID = 2.5.4.97        # Don't touch this

[dn]
C = FO
ST = Foobar Monarchy
O = Lorem Ipsum
CN = specific.domain.com
OrganizationID = ABCDE-12345
#...

[v3_req]
#...
```

`RS=<null>` puts awk into blank-line-separated paragraph mode (see `RS = ""` in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line), `ORS='\n\n'` ensures a blank-line separated output, `$0 = "\n" $0` ensures every line of the record has a newline before it so that the subsequent `sub()` using surrounding newlines can succeed even if `OrganizationID` is the first line of the record and then `sub(/^\n/,"")` removes the temporary newline we added in the first step.

Comment: I see, so this processing happens only within the `[dn]` paragraph - I guess I could substitute the literal `ABCDE-12345` with another argument variable, like: `awk -v RS= -v ORS=\n\n -v MYOUT=${REQ_ID} ' ... "\nOrganizationID = $MYOUT")...'` ? Thank you for the hint, will try tomorrow

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the right syntax to do that. I just updated my answer to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Method1

```
for  i in `sed -n '/OrganizationID/{;=;}' file| sed -n '2p'`; do sed ''$i's/.*/OrganizationID = ABCDE-98765/g' file; done
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
j=[]
t=0
h=re.compile(r'OrganizationID.*')
k=open('file','r')
for i in k:
    if re.search(h,i):
        t=t+1
        if (t == 2):
            y=re.sub(h,"OrganizationID = ABCDE-98765",i)
            print y.strip()
        else:
            print i.strip()
    else:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
oid_section = OIDs

[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

attributes = v3_req

[OIDs]
OrganizationID = 2.5.4.97        # Don't touch this

[dn]
C = FO
ST = Foobar Monarchy
O = Lorem Ipsum
CN = specific.domain.com
OrganizationID = ABCDE-98765
```

Comment: I will admit, I'm having some trouble understanding the code in Method1 - could you explain in a bit more detail? I'm not familiar with the meaning of `{;=;}` in the very first step, f.e., or why is the for loop necessary (does the loop run once per occurrence? how does it recognize the second one?)

Comment: Copy/paste that first script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about the issues we always tell you about with your scripts.

Comment: I am trying to improve my answers @EdMorton

Comment: I and others have told you **MANY** times about using http://shellcheck.net to check your code, how to use quotes properly (and referred you to https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), that backticks are deprecated (and referred you to (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), not to use `for i in` to read lines (and referred you to https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), etc. If you're really trying to improve your answers then just follow that advice. Especially given http://shellcheck.net will tell you about most issues it should be easy not to keep repeating the same problems.

Comment: You could, for example, copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net right now, fix the issues it tells you about, and then edit your answer to show the vastly improved code instead of what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish the task using Awk. We place the REQ_ID onto the environment of awk command line from where it gets available in the builtin associative array ENVIRON

```
$ REQ_ID="ABCDE-98765" \
   awk '
     BEGIN { a[1] = "OrganizationID = " ENVIRON["REQ_ID"] }
     $1 == "[dn]", match($0, /^OrganizationID[[:blank:]]*=/) {
       a[0] = $0
       $0 = a[RSTART]
     }1
  ' ssl.cfg
```

With sed there's some more work because we have to ensure that the REQ_ID is placeable on the RHS of the s/// command.

```
$ REQ_ID="ABCDE-98765"; s="[[:blank:]]" 
$ req_id_esc=$(printf '%s\n' "$REQ_ID" | sed -e 's:[\&/]:\\&:g')
$ sed -e "/^[[]dn]/,/^OrganizationID$s*=/s/^\(OrganizationID\)$s*=.*/\1 = ${req_id_esc}/" ssl.cfg
```

```
$ REQ_ID="ABCDE-98765" \
   perl -pale '
      s//$1 = $ENV{REQ_ID}/ if 
        $F[0] eq "[dn]" ... /^(OrganizationID)\s*=.*/ and
        defined $1' ssl.cfg
```