# String manipulation and piping it to bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with contents like this:

```
...
    packageEARTH {
        ...
    }
    packageMARS {
        ...
    }
    packageVENUS {
        ...
    }
...
```

So I want to do a multi-step process. I want to extract every word starting with the word "package".
So that would be:

```
packageEARTH
packageMARS
packageVENUS
```

Then in the next step I would like to append text to the front and the end of each word like so:

```
./builder makepackageEARTHMain ; ./builder makepackageMARSMain ; ./builder makepackageVENUSMain
```

So that it becomes executable in bash.

Last step is to add a `clean` command after every 30 `makepackage`s. So finally it would become:

```
./builder makepackageEARTHMain ; ..x30.. ; ./builder cleancache ; ..x30.. ; ./builder cleancache
```

*Here `...x30...` means 30 times makepackage command*

And finally to pipe it to bash so the commands can run sequentially.
I'm not that familiar with awk or sed, So if anyone could help me understand how to solve this it'd be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: @chzzh haha, Ik. Native options allow me to run all of these commands with one command but I don't want to do that. Because it stops altogether if there's error in any of the build and it fills up the disk very fast so I need to be running that clean cache command every 30 commands to prevent that.

Comment: @chzzh Nope. That's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/package[[:alnum:]_]+/) {
    sep = (cnt++ ? " ; " : "")
    printf "%s./builder make%sMain", sep, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    if ( !(cnt % 2) ) {
        printf "%s./builder cleancache", sep
    }
}
END { print "" }


$ awk -f tst.awk file
./builder makepackageEARTHMain ; ./builder makepackageMARSMain ; ./builder cleancache ; ./builder makepackageVENUSMain
```

Just change `2` to `30` to get the `cleancache` statement printed after every 30 instead of after every 2 packages.

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully!

Comment: how do I modify this script so I can skip some of the builds. Sometimes it fails in between and if I want to start from a certain point, how do I add a second parameter? Using `-v foo=MARS`  I can't access $foo inside? How do I pass parameters with -f? Thanks

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a shell to execute commands. You could do the whole thing with `perl` as:

```
perl -ne '
  for (/\bpackage\w+\b/g) {
    system "./builder", "make${_}Main";
    system "./builder", "cleancache" unless ++$n % 30
  }' input-file
```

Comment: Hm. I tried using this, it isn't working. I think this is not matching the word `package`

Answer (score 0):

Done and tested by awk

```
 to=`awk 'END{print NR}' p.txt`

awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^package/){print "./builder " "Make"$i"Main"}}}' p.txt| awk -v to="$to" '{for(i=30;i<=to;i++){if(NR==i){$0=$0"\n./builder cleancache"}{i=i+29}}}1'
```

Comment: [You said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600723/replacing-a-matched-string-occurring-after-another-specific-string-in-a-file/600760?noredirect=1#comment1122033_600760) "I am trying to improve my answers" but here you are again using backticks instead of `$(...)` despite repeated previous advice from multiple people so I'm not sure what it is you're doing to try to improve them. I'm not going to comment on your answers any more as neither of us are getting any benefit from me doing so - hopefully others will help you improve and all the best with your programming.